# How using Spark read Hive DOUBLE value stored in Avro logical format

Tags: apache-spark, binary, hive, double, avro

I have existing Hive data stored in Avro format. For whatever reason reading these data by executing SELECT is very slow. I didn't figure out yet why. The data is partitioned and my WHERE clause always follows the partition columns. So I decided to read the data directly by navigating to the partition path and using Spark SQLContext. This works much faster. However, the problem I have is reading the DOUBLE values. Avro stores them in a binary format.
When I execute the following query in Hive:

```
select myDoubleValue from myTable;
```

I'm getting the correct expected values

```
841.79
4435.13
.....
```

but the following Spark code:

```
    val path="PathToMyPartition"
    val sqlContext = new SQLContext(sc)
    val df = sqlContext.read.avro(path)
    df.select("myDoubleValue").rdd.map(x => x.getAs[Double](0))
```

gives me this exception

```
java.lang.ClassCastException : [B cannot be cast to java.lang.Double
```

What would be the right way either to provide a schema or convert the value that is stored in a binary format into a double format?

Comment: Your value has came in string format? What is the format of the data in the dataframe?

Comment: When I run df.schema the relevant field has format like this: binary (nullable = true) so I assume, also based on the error I'm getting, that it is binary

Answer (score 0):

I found a partial solution how to convert the Avro schema to a Spark SQL StructType. There is com.databricks.spark.avro.SchemaConverters developed by Databricks that has a bug in converting Avro logical data types in their toSqlType(avroSchema: Schema) method which was incorrectly converting the logicalType

```
{"name":"MyDecimalField","type":["null",{"type":"bytes","logicalType":"decimal","precision":38,"scale":18}],"doc":"","default":null}
```

into

```
StructField("MyDecimalField",BinaryType,true)
```

I fixed this bug in my local version of the code and now it is converting into

```
StructField("MyDecimalField",DecimalType(38,18),true)
```

Now, the following code reads the Avro file and creates a Dataframe:

```
val avroSchema = new Schema.Parser().parse(QueryProvider.getQueryString(pathSchema))
val sqlContext = new SQLContext(sc)
val df = sqlContext.read.schema(MyAvroSchemaConverter.toSqlType(avroSchema).dataType.asInstanceOf[StructType]).avro(path)
```

However, when I'm selecting the filed that I expect to be decimal by

```
df.select("MyDecimalField")
```

I'm getting the following exception:

```
scala.MatchError: [B@3e6e0d8f (of class [B)
```

This is where I stuck at this time and would appreciate if anyone can suggest what to do next or any other work around.